# Set dev environment in php with apache (http.conf)

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, httpd.conf

I would like to set Dev/prod env . to my php application 
How can I do that?
is is possible to do that in the http.conf? if yes how its can be done via mac and windows with apache 2.4 ?
Something like:    setEnv Dev

then how can I grab the data from the config file

my user conf file:

```
<Directory "/Users/usename/Sites/">
        AllowOverride All
      SetEnv VARNAME myvariable
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and its not working